# ERROR Installing Pkg.add("IJulia"): no active project

Tags: julia, using, ijulia-notebook

I want to install Julia in my jupyter notebook. I am getting this. I am not able to find what means the reference to 'no active Project'. Any help will be very welcomed. Thanks

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
ERROR: no active project
Stacktrace:
  [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
    @ Pkg.Types C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\Types.jl:68
  [2] find_project_file(env::Nothing)
    @ Pkg.Types C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\Types.jl:200
  [3] Pkg.Types.EnvCache(env::Nothing) (repeats 2 times)
    @ Pkg.Types C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\Types.jl:319
  [4] Pkg.Types.Context()
    @ Pkg.Types .\util.jl:478
  [5] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; io::Base.TTY, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Pkg.API C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:145
  [6] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})
    @ Pkg.API C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:144
  [7] #add#27
    @ C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:142 [inlined]
  [8] add
    @ C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:142 [inlined]
  [9] #add#26
    @ C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:141 [inlined]
 [10] add(pkg::String)
    @ Pkg.API C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Pkg\src\API.jl:141
 [11] top-level scope
    @ REPL[36]:1

julia>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a new environment user path as JULIA_HOME to the following route:
C:\Users\madel\Julia-1.7.2\bin and works now. It seems like I was not pointing the right path.

Comment: Do you mean that you set a new environment variable `JULIA_HOME` in your shell, and that solved the problem? As far as I know, `JULIA_HOME` is an old outdated variable that's not in use anymore. So I'm curious how this solved anything. Are you sure you didn't change anything else in the meantime?

Comment: Also curious how the original issue happened, first of all. Could you also mention how you installed Julia - did you download it from julialang.org, or get it from the Windows Store, or something else?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right. I downloaded from https://julialang.org/downloads/ the last realease is v1.7.2. Basically, I installed Julia and after that a reinstalled anaconda. From there I open Julia command line and install Pkg, nothing special here. I am still searching about the environment issue. Right now, I get Julia in my resgistry and uploaded into jupyter so JULIA_HOME doesn't make anything so I need to reproduce initial condition to do the same so will post once I get something interesting.